# (VIM) Is vimgrep capable of searching unicode string

Tags: vim, unicode, vimgrep

Is vimgrep capable of searching unicode strings? 
For example:
[image]

`a.txt` contains wide string "hello",  `vimgrep hello *.txt` found nothing, and of course it's in the right path.

Comment: What do you mean "wide string"? "hello" is not really a good example of unicode. Is `a.txt` in your working directory?

Comment: By "wide string" I mean unicode string, I've updated the post with an image. "a.txt" is in the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unicode" is a bit misleading in this case. What you have is not at all typical of text "encoded in accordance with any of the method provided by the Unicode standard". It's a bunch of normal characters with normal code points separated with NULL characters with code point `0000` or `00`. Some Java programs do output that kind of garbage.

So, if your search pattern is `hello`, Vim and `:vim` are perfectly capable of searching for and finding `hello` (without NULLs) but they won't ever find `hello` (with NULLs).

Searching for `h^@e^@l^@l^@o` (`^@` is `<C-v><C-@>`), on the other hand, will find `hello` (with NULLs) but not `hello` (without NULLs).

Anyway, converting that file/buffer or making sure you don't end up with such a garbage are much better long-term solutions.

Comment: Is UTF-16 Little Endian not Unicode? Or does the standard require a BOM? I thought the BOM was always optional.

Comment: It is not "all of unicode". "hello" and "hello" are both "unicode" but one is nice and the other is a nightmare. So yeah, Vim can perfectly work with "unicode" as long as the user is aware of what he is working with.

Answer (score 1):

If Vim can detect the encoding of the file, then yes, Vim can grep the file. `:vimgrep` works by first reading in the file as normal (even including autocmds) into a hidden buffer, and then searching the buffer.

It looks like your file is little-endian UTF-16, without a byte-order mark (BOM). Vim *can* detect this, but won't by default.

First, make sure your Vim is running with internal support for unicode. To do that, `:set encoding=utf-8` at the top of your .vimrc. Next, Vim needs to be able to detect this file's encoding. The `'fileencodings'` option controls this.

By default, when you set 'encoding' to utf-8, Vim's 'fileencodings' option contains "ucs-bom" which will detect UTF-16, but ONLY if a BOM is present. To also detect it when no BOM is present, you need to add your desired encoding to 'fileencodings'. It needs to come before any of the 8-bit encodings but after ucs-bom. Try doing this at the top of your .vimrc and restart Vim to use:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-16le,utf-8,default,latin1
```

Now loading files with the desired encoding should work just fine for editing, and therefore also for vimgrep.